# Microsoft Access 2013 - Multiple Foreign Keys in the same Record

Tags: database

I’ve encountered a problem with pulling multiple foreign keys into one record in a Microsoft Access table.

I’ve got two tables with these fields:

Table 1: 
Owners
Fields:
Owner ID (Primary Key)
First Name
Last Name

Table 2:
Ships
Fields:
Ship ID (Primary Key)
Ship Name

I need to create a relationship between Table 1 and Table 2 which shows who owns the ship. I’ve tried adding a number field to Table 2 called Owner ID (Foreign Key) and this works absolutely fine.

Working Example:

```
Table 1 – Owners                  Table 2 – Ships 
Owner ID (Primary Key)__          Ship ID (Primary Key)
First Name              \         Ship Name
Last Name                \________Owner ID (Foreign Key)
```

Unfortunately my ships in Table 2 can have multiple owners (up to 5) at the same time. My problem arises when I try to create a series of linking fields in Table 2.

Not Working:

```
Table 1 – Owners                     Table 2 – Ships 
Owner ID (Primary Key)__             Ship ID (Primary Key)
First Name              \            Ship Name
Last Name                \           Owner1 ID (Foreign Key)
                          \______/   Owner2 ID (Foreign Key)
                                 \   Owner3 ID (Foreign Key)
```

Can anyone recommend any workarounds so I can show multiple owners taken from the Owners table in the Ships table?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is not working? If you add the five fields, and define a relation for _each_ of them _separately_(!) it should work fine. Your diagram gives me the feeling you tried to create 1 relationship, when in fact you want to create 5 of them/

Comment: After trying a bit, it can easily work, but you just have to ensure you do not edit the existing relationship (Access asked me if I wanted that). Instead, it add's a copy of your table_1 to your relations-diagram and makes the relation there. Confusing and imho unnecessary, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Your database design is definitely incorrect.

In the case you explain, you have a many-to-many relationship between Ships and Owners, which MUST translate into a "relationship table" in the relational model.
In this case: a [Ownership] table, with 2 fields, being the 2 Primary Keys (PK) of the related tables.

In other words, you need 3 tables:

- Ships(ShipId, ShipName, Whatever)  PK is ShipId
- Owner(OwnerId, FirstName, LastName)  PK is OwnerId
- OwnerShip(ShipId, OwnerId)       PK is made of the 2 FKs

Comment: If there can ever be more than those 5 owners, your are right. But That does not answer the OP's question :) The same problem can arise when i want to include a Customer ShipFrom and a CustomerShipTo in a table, both referencing my customertable.

Comment: @oerkelens: with a correct design, the question *would not exist*. And I maintain my point of view. The limitation to 5 owners is a constraint that does not constitue an exemption for a proper 3rd or 4th NF

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it looks like Access doesn't allow Nullable FK's and so all Owner fields would have to be filled in, no matter how many owners there are.

The only solution to this I can think of is to introduce a ShipOwner table, which has ShipID and OwnerID columns (as FK's to the Ship and Owner tables). You can then have as many Owners as you like.

```
Pros: You can add things like %Owned if that matters
Cons: The software has to enforce the limit of 5 owners
```

Biggest Pro: it will work!

Cheers -

EDIT: The first para is wrong: Access does let you add nullable FK's. However I still thing the suggestion here is a good one. Repeating Groups (Owner 1 to 5) is against Normalisation rules, and this suggestion is normalised.

Comment: Since when does Access not allow nullable fields, be they foreign key's or not? I'd like to see a source of that :)

Comment: It does, but these are I think Long Number and it wouldn't let me set them null when I tried (Access 2013).

Comment: Just tried in 2010 and it works :) You made me wonder myself :)

Comment: I am having a little diff here. I have one table. Primary key of this table is set as Foreign key to two different table. But when I am doing so I did not get any results from table. I us MS Access 2013. What I need to do to map this relationship? Any Steps?